# Maps Directions Service - Avoid given Waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I have an array of Waypoints which are in my example a no-go area and therefore not allowed to get chosen by google DirectionsService. Is there a way to say that to the google DirectionsService?

Searched in the docs for that feature, but couldn´t find something about it.
Are any workarounds out there/ possible?

Comment: Not from what I can see from the docs

Comment: Hoped that I just didn´t found it. Could be a new feature request then.

Comment: [Feature request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214) (created 2008...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

[Feature request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214) (created 2008...)